# Updating Armadillo on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, armadillo

I currently have Armadillo 9.900.4 installed on my machine with Ubuntu 20.04. I have downloaded 10.1.0 and ran `cmake .` and `sudo make install` and when I recompile my code and run it it says it was compiled with 9.900.4. Am I do something wrong? Is there a way to fully remove armadillo and reinstall?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the drawback of using `make install` to install something. It circumvents your distro package manager and then you have to manually clean/upgrade what you have installed like that. It's also up to the creator of the library what the `install` make target actually does.

Some libraries also create a "uninstall" target to make uninstalling easier. I don't know if armadillo does that, but you can just try running `make uninstall` from the folder where you compiled and run the `make install` command to check.

In any case, Linux has standard directories where libraries and headers are installed. Usually all that the `install` make target does is to copy the appropriated files to these folders. Then all you need to do is to delete these files manually. Try to look in the `/usr/include` folder for the headers, and in the `/usr/lib` folder for the compiled libraries (the name can vary a little from distribution to distribution).

If you can't find them, you can use the `locate` program. Just run `locate armadillo` in the shell. I'm not sure if it is already installed in ubuntu, though.

---

You might also just use armadillo as a header only library without "installing it" in your system. In that case, you will need to link your program with a BLAS implementation as well as Lapack. In fact, when you compile armadillo all it does is to create a "wrapper library" that you can link with and that already links with BLAS and Lapack (most of armadillo code is templated code).

---

TLDR;

Search in the `/usr/include` (or something similar) for armadillo readers and delete them. Search for in the `/usr/lib` (or something similar) for the compiled armadillo library and delete it.